# Image does not show on button Tkinter

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I'm trying to simply add an image to a tkinter button. I tried everything:

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('300x300+300+150')
photo = tk.PhotoImage('home.gif')
btn = tk.Button(root, image = photo, width = 100, height = 100)
btn.image = photo  # even with this does not work
btn.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

I also tried with PIL setting the `photo` variable equal to `ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('home.gif'))`, I tried easly the `open` function, the absolute path of the photo (and yes, the photo is inside the same directory of my script), but anything works. The window just pop up with a big button, without image inside.

UPDATE:
I tried with other images, and I noticed that some images are shown while others no. This is because the images with transparent background cause a bug or a problem to tkinter... so, I do not know if there's a way to solve this. On google I find out that some people use canvas but I actually need the image to be inside the button so I do not know how to do.

Comment: `photo = tk.PhotoImage('home.gif')` should be `photo = tk.PhotoImage(file='home.gif')`

Comment: does not work anyway·

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA i thought `file` was a positional argument?

Comment: try removing the `width` and the `height` from the button, then try using the images on the root window and not on a button

Comment: @CoolCloud No, `file` is a keyword argument in `tkinter.PhotoImage()`.

Comment: Changing to `photo = tk.PhotoImage(file='...')` works for me.  Any error shown on the console if it is executed in a terminal? Check whether the image is actually a GIF image.

Comment: I can't remove width and height cause i want the button of a certain size, but if i do so it does not work anyway. No, any errors are shown in the terminal. Yes, mine is a gif image

Comment: @Gianla i believe the button will automatically resize to fit the whole image in.

Comment: what system do you use - Windows, Linux, Mac? Maybe on some systems it makes problem if you use transparent background. Did you try to use `PIL` ? It may work better with some formats. Do you need transparency ? If not then use any Image Editor/viewer and convert images to version without transparency.

Comment: please read the update.

Answer (score 1):

Please change your code as below

`photo = tk.PhotoImage(file='home.gif')`

because i changed the above code and it worked....

Comment: This does not make any sense. If I pass an argument to a function that as first argument has a keyword arg the argument that I pass will be automatically assigned at the first keyword argument that the function was asking for. And it does not work in anyway.

Comment: @Gianla: it works, because `file` is not the first positional argument. When you pass a filename as the first positional argument, that is treated as the name of the image object, not the file used to create the image object.